# Сайт на wordpress грузит CPU сервера на 100%

Tags: wordpress

При добавлении  постов или редактировании  нагрузка скачет до 100%. Что это может быть?

Из плагинов установлены Acf, polylang, contact form, all in one seo, post dublicator.

Также выбивает ошибку:

> “Connection lost. Saving has been disabled until you’re reconnected.”

Comment: Установите xhprof и запрофилируйте. Вы точно узнаете, что, где, когда тормозит. Или включайте плагины "по одному", так вы увлекательно потратите время, поймете примерно где, но почему - так и останется загадкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Редактирование постов в wp создает достаточно большую нагрузку на базу данных. Если Вы уверенны, что такая нагрузка не должна создаваться, то я бы советовал отключить все плагины, проверить нагрузку на сервер. И включать по одному плагину, и смотреть нагрузку, так Вы сможете выяснить, какой именно плагин нагружает сервер.